# converting datetime in sqlserver like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss to yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Hi I want to convert the date time like below `2015-05-12 23:59:59`. The hours and secs and  should come like `12:59:59` this.

**Ex:** I want to convert today's date like below `2015-08-17 23:59:59`.

**Edited**

for GETDATE() in sql server I will get the datetime like this 2015-08-17 17:10:54.080   this one I want to convert into 2015-08-17 23:59:59.080

Comment: what do you mean by converting 2015-08-17 17:10:54.080 into 2015-08-17 23:59:59.080 ? The times here are different. That is also conflicting with your header where you are requesting a different format

Comment: Hi I updated my header.sorry for the confusion @t-clausen.dk

Comment: Almost always, this is solving the wrong problem. When working with continuous data, it's almost always better to work with semi-open intervals (inclusive start point, exclusive end point). It's trivial to work out "midnight at the start of tomorrow" rather than "the last moment of today" and the latter won't need changing if you later change data types (e.g. the last moment of a day when working with `datetime2` differs depending on the precision, and none of them is the same as for `datetime`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems this question is not about formatting. So here is a solution to get last timestamps of the day:

To get the last minute of the day:

```
SELECT dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()), cast('23:59:59' as datetime))
```

Returns:

```
2015-08-17 23:59:59.000
```

To get the last possible timestamp of the day:

```
SELECT dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()), cast('23:59:59:997' as datetime))
2015-08-17 23:59:59.997
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `convert()` here, try below query

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(19), GetDate(),121)
```

**Output :**

```
2015-08-17 11:37:29
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `CHAR(19)` to eliminate the last `.` .

Comment: use 120 instead of 121 then the problem is solved, milliseconds is not needed

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV already solved, can you please try this query? I think it doesn't mention to display milliseconds.

Comment: yes i understood i mean you can use 120 instead of 121, because 121 gives milliseconds too , and 120 only return hh:mm:ss

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thanks for clarification i have delete that comment

Comment: @t-clausen.dk but still i am confused how 2015-08-17 17:10:54.080  converted to  2015-08-17 23:59:59.080 ???

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**CAST**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to `TIME(0)` what will return your time in following format:
`HH:mm:ss`

```
SELECT CAST('2015-08-17 12:59:59' AS TIME(0))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
12:59:59
```

---

**CORRECTION**

Misunderstood your question before, so provided how to get only time, for date + time in following format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` you can use in following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), '2015-08-17 12:59:59.154', 20)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2015-08-17 12:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

### SQL Server 2005 and Later

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
```

### SQL Server 2012 and later versions

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE() , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Either will return:

```
2015-08-17 12:42:25
```

Comment: really a down vote to this answer???? would you care to leave a comment as well I maybe be able to improve my answer then?